# UISplitViewController popover is blank

Tags: iphone, uipopovercontroller, ipad

I am using UISplitViewController with UITabbarController as master view and navigation controller as detail view. Each of the tabs on the master view contain a navigation controller. When any of the tabs on the master view are selected, a view is pushed on the detail view navigation controller.

```
recentsviewController = [[RecentsViewController_ipad alloc]initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:nil];
recentsNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:recentsviewController]; 

//similarly rootNav and favNav

NSArray* controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:recentsNav,self.rootNav,favNav,nil];  
self.tabbarController.viewControllers = controllers;

detailViewController=[[LoginViewController_ipad alloc]init];
detailNav=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:detailViewController];

splitViewController =[[UISplitViewController alloc]init];
splitViewController.viewControllers=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.tabbarController,self.detailNav,nil];
    splitViewController.delegate = self.detailViewController;

[self.window addSubview:splitViewController.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

This seems to work fine. When app goes into portrait mode a 'Browse' button is added to the navigation bar. Clicking this button shows the hidden view along with the tabs perfectly fine. I can switch between the tabs and work on the views displayed in the popover. When tapped on other than popover area the popover is dismissed as expected.

The two things that are not working are

1. The popover has to show up on its own each time app switches to portrait mode without the user having to select the button added to nav bar
2. On some occasions I need to dismiss the popover programatically.

I have tried foll code :

```
- (void)splitViewController: (UISplitViewController*)svc willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem*)barButtonItem forPopoverController: (UIPopoverController*)pc {
barButtonItem.title = @"Browse";
[[self navigationItem] setLeftBarButtonItem:barButtonItem];
self.appDelegate.rootPopoverButtonItem = barButtonItem;
self.appDelegate.splitViewPopover = pc;
[self.appDelegate.splitViewPopover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:self.appDelegate.rootPopoverButtonItem permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:NO];
}
```

This adds a black translucent popover each time the orientation changes. How do I make it show what the browse button shows when it is clicked?
The usual dismissPopvoerAnimated does not seem to work here.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: fixed the issue